# HTML/JavaScript - Determine how many pages to be printed

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, reporting

I'm developing a single page app that fetches data from the back-end to an AngularJS controller and then shows them in some grids and charts and stuff like that using KendoUI. Then I want to generate reports of these grids and I want it to be print-friendly; still fine.

The problem is that I want to add a footer row at the end of each printed page, that contains sum of all rows in that page, which I can't, because I got no idea about how many pages it takes and how many rows would fit in a page after printing.

I tried different ways like creating PDFs but the other issue is that most of pdf libs don't support UTF and that's something that I need.

What I want is: to have the number the of row elements in each "Printed" page, then I would calculate the sum row and add it to that "page". In fact I need something like "page-break event" or something like that, as the whole job would take place in JS runtime. But there seems no way to do this when printing HTML directly, Because the browser is the one that deals with the printer.

So the only way I found is to fix row heights and calculate how many rows each page contains, And hope that users don't change the paper size.
Is there any way?

PS. I wonder why I didn't find anyone with this issue. Because it's very common in report generators to calculate total of values in a page when printing.

Comment: HTML/CSS isn't really designed for paged media even if there is ome support. I don't think it is reliably possible to do what you want. I have only little experience with PDF, but I can't imagine that PDF libraries don't support UTF-8 properly. What environment/language do you use server-side?

Comment: True. I'm convinced that there's no such thing as 'Page Break Event'. I tried to use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12) which have no UTF support, yet. And there are other libs but with the same problem, or messing with right-to-left languages. They have ASP.NET on the server and there are plenty of report generating APIs that do this job server-side, But 'they' want it to be done client-side. And thanks for comment anyway.